# Echo an img and put in a php statement inside the src?

Tags: php, wordpress

How would I format this correctly? I know I can't open a php statement inside an existing one but I'm not sure how to correct it.

```
echo '<img src="<?php echo dirname( get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ); ?>/images/isa.jpg" alt="ISA">';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
echo '<img src="'.dirname( get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ).'/images/isa.jpg" alt="ISA">';
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll make sure to remember concatenation from now on. Also, I'll check your answer in 5 min.

Answer (score 1):

do it like this

```
echo '<img src="'.dirname( get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ).'"/images/isa.jpg" alt="ISA">';
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use PHP's [`printf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) and [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) for that. It's easier to visualize the HTML and we just need to fill it with `%s` and their corresponding build up.

```
printf(
    '<img src="%s/images/isa.jpg" alt="ISA">', // base HTML
    dirname( get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url') )  // first %s converted element
);
```

Answer (score 0):

IT is better to use get_template_directory_uri() rather than get_bloginfo(). You can use following code:

```
echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/isa.jpg" alt="ISA">';
```